# Python - Finding Row Discrepancies Between Two Dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes with the same number of columns, d1 and d2.

NOTE: d1 and d2 may have different number of rows.
NOTE: d1 and d2 may not be indexed to the same row in each data frame.

What is the best way to check whether or not the two dataframes have the same data?

My current solution consists of appending the two dataframes together and dropping any rows that match.

```
d_combined = d1.append(d2)
d_discrepancy = d_combined.drop_duplicates(keep=False)
print(d_discrepancy)
```

I am new to python and the pandas library. Because I will be using dataframes with millions of rows and 8-10 columns, is there a faster and more efficient way to check for discrepancies? Can it also be shown which initial dataframe the resulting discrepancy row is from?

Answer (score 2):

**Setup**

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[1, 2, 3, 4]))
d2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[2, 3, 4, 5]))
```

**Option 1**
Use `pd.merge`.  I'll include the parameter `indicator=True` to show where the data came from.

```
d1.merge(d2, how='outer', indicator=True)

   A      _merge
0  1   left_only
1  2        both
2  3        both
3  4        both
4  5  right_only
```

If they have the same data, I'd expect that the `_merge` column would be `both` for everything.  So we can check with

```
d1.merge(d2, how='outer', indicator=True)._merge.eq('both').all()

False
```

In this case, it returned `False` therefore not the same data.

---

**Option 2**
Use `drop_duplicates`
You need to make sure you drop the duplicates from the initial dataframes first.

```
d1.drop_duplicates().append(d2.drop_duplicates()) \
    .drop_duplicates(keep=False).empty
```